# I have an import export error in react-redux boiler plate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

while I tried to run my react-redux app using `npm start` it shows **Attempted import error: 'store' is not exported from './app/store'.**. error is in my `index.js` file.

this is my `store.js` file

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import counterReducer from '../features/counterSlice';

export default configureStore({
reducer: {
counter: counterReducer,
},
});
```

this is my `index.js` file

**index.js**

````
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { store } from './app/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1e6q.png
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```js
import store from './app/store';
```

This is because in your `app/store` you are using  `export default` on the object.
Objects that are exported by default, do not need to be specified within curly braces.

Read the top of [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) to see various syntax styles.

If you were to export another object from the `app/store` file, then you'd have to specify it in the following way:

```js
import store, { anotherObj } from './app/store';
```

Comment: I've added an explanation to your answer. However, next time you write an answer consider doing this yourself; it makes your answer more valuable to the community.

Answer (score 2):

You've got mismatched imports and exports.

`store.js` is doing a *default* export:

```js
export default configureStore()
```

But `index.js` is doing a *named* import:

```js
import { store } from './app/store';
```

You need to use the same pattern on both sides. Either `export default configureStore()` and `import store`, or `export const store = configureStore()` and `import {store}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your import in index.js file for the store.js should be like:

```
import store from './app/store.js'; (Changes according to your file structure).
```

But do not use brackets.